# Converting two bytes to one byte and vice versa

Tags: c#, binary, byte

I need to develop two functions to do combine and separate operations on bytes.

```
public byte Combine(Byte a, Byte b)
{
    // ... Operations ...
}

public byte[] Separate(Byte input)
{
    // ... Operations ...
}

public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    Byte a, b, c;
    a = <SOME BYTE VALUE>;
    b = <SOME OTHER BYTE VALUE>;

    Console.Writeline("Before Operation");
    Console.Writeline("a = " + Convert.ToString(a, 2));
    Console.Writeline("b = " + Convert.ToString(b, 2));

    // Combine Function called...
    c = Combine(a, b);

    // Separate Function called...
    byte[] d = Separate(c);

    a = d[0];
    b = d[1];

    Console.Writeline("After Operation");
    Console.Writeline("a = " + Convert.ToString(a, 2));
    Console.Writeline("b = " + Convert.ToString(b, 2));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I have tried many things like performing combination of **AND, OR, XOR, NAND, NOT** and **LEFT** as well as **RIGHT SHIFT** operations on this to achieve the above functionality.
I just want to know is there any way to do this or Wether to write this type of function is at all possible in the first place.
Please I need your valuable suggestions and comments...

Comment: This is impossible. See the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: There is no possiblity to store two bytes as one byte in way that allows to reproduce input. The only way I see to store two `Int16` numbers inside `Int32` - it can be done with a little kownledge how 32-bit `int` is stored and shift operations.

Comment: You are converting a large set of values (2 bytes) into a smaller set (1 byte).  You will definitely end up with collisions and therefore not be able to reliably map the 1 byte back to the original 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you can see in comment, you cannot store 2 bytes inside 1 byte. If could achieve it, you would probably be the most genius person in the world - every single data could be compressed twice!

Instead you can store two 16-bit ints inside 32-bit int:

```
public static uint ToInt(ushort first, ushort second)
{
    return (uint)(first << 16) | second;
}

public static ushort ExtractFirst(uint val)
{
    return (ushort)((val >> 16) & ushort.MaxValue);
}

public static ushort ExtractSecond(uint val)
{
    return (ushort)(val & ushort.MaxValue);
}
```

Next, we can store two bytes as one 16-bit `int`:

```
public static ushort ToShort(byte first, byte second)
{
    return (ushort)((first << 8) | second);
}

public static byte ExtractFirst(ushort location)
{
    return (byte)((location >> 8) & byte.MaxValue);
}

public static byte ExtractSecond(ushort location)
{
    return (byte)(location & byte.MaxValue);
}
```